# Isotope JS Multiple Checkbox FIlters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I have these checkboxes here in two different sections:

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 choose_lifestyle">

    <input type="checkbox" id="fiftyfiveplus" name="fiftyfiveplus" value=".fiftyfiveplus">
    <label for="fiftyfiveplus">55+ Exclusive</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="allages" name="allages" value=".allages">
    <label for="allages">All-Ages</label> 

</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 builder-pick">  
    <input id="cbx_classic" type="checkbox" name="cbx_classic" value=".classic-group" />
    <label for="cbx_classic">Classic Homes</label>

    <input id="cbx_nvhomes" type="checkbox" name="cbx_nvhomes" value=".nvhomes" />
    <label for="cbx_nvhomes">NVHomes</label>

    <input id="cbx_ryan" type="checkbox" name="cbx_ryan" value=".ryan-homes" />
    <label for="cbx_ryan">Ryan Homes</label>

    <input id="cbx_winchester" type="checkbox" name="cbx_winchester" value=".winchester-homes" />
    <label for="cbx_winchester">Winchester Homes</label>
</div>

<!-- Some example results -->
<div id="wpv-view-layout-99-TCPID101">
  <div class="home_wrapper allages classic-group">

  </div>
  <div class="home_wrapper fiftyfiveplus classic-group">

  </div>
  <div class="home_wrapper fiftyfiveplus nvhomes">

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for isotope:

```
var container = jQuery('#wpv-view-layout-99-TCPID101 > .row');
     var checkboxes = jQuery("input[type='checkbox']");

     container.isotope({
          itemSelector: '.home_wrapper'
     });

     var isotope = container.data('isotope');


     checkboxes.change(function() {
          var filters = [];
          // get checked checkboxes values
          checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
               filters.push(this.value);
          });

          console.log(filters);
          filters = filters.join(', ');
          container.isotope({
               filter: filters
          });

     });
```

How do I combine filters?

For example if I select fiftyfiveplus, then classic-group afterwards from the builder-pick select boxes, I should see only the divs that contain "fiftyfiveplus classic-group". At the moment, it shows all allages and fiftyfiveplus entries.

I found a good example here on how to combine:

https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JEojz

But can't figure out how to implement it into my version.

Comment: May already be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339621/joining-multiple-checkbox-filters-within-isotope-js

Answer (score 1):

Some of the relevant CSS would help to apply a full snippet demo, however, you can try Natu's suggested [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339621/joining-multiple-checkbox-filters-within-isotope-js) approach:

- Replace `filters = filters.join(', ');` for `filters =
  filters.join('');`

This should add & combine the selected options instead of filtering either one or the other, as stated with the comma.